# Cost Estimation for mobile app development

Tags: price, estimation

We have a project at hand where in we have to develop a mobile application that runs in both android and iOS. We are 3 people working on it. Client doesnt care what technology we use for development. We are making a hybrid app with JS,HTML,CSS, phonegap and also native coding in some places.

Application is not so complex. But we are all newbies to it so learning and implementing things. Now the tough part is doing cost estimation.

What are the things to consider while estimating costs?
We live in Bangalore, India

Your answers are appreciated..

Comment: Check topics from here as well http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes. In short, you have to know how many work hours it will take x your hourly rate

Comment: go through the blog for cost estimation : http://blaze-core.com/much-cost-develop-app-game/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need to derive the minimum hourly rate for your location.

Then you need to calculate the time required for doing the things and just multiply it with hourly rate.

Here one thing you need to consider in mind is that you also consider the testing part in the time estimation.

At the beginning try to calculate how much money you need for living in 1 month. The divide it to 4 weeks and that is money you have to earn in 1 week. You may further divide it with 40 to get your hourly rate.

And this is the MIN hourly rate only IF you work 40 hours a week. Many freelancers will double or triple their hourly rates because you can hardly work 40 hours a week as a beginner and you need to earn your living somehow.

Thats all enjoy freelancing.

refer the answer of Peter here [How do I estimate the cost of building an Android app?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/cost-of-an-android-app-newbie-help)

Comment: Great answer @Blaze-Core. Also very important: after the project is done make sure you know if the support is free and if so for how long. You don't want to pay put of your own pocket especially if you work with a small margin